# Source errors in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When I create a new android project appearing red exclamation mark
and when I tried to run the app the message say

> Android library projects cannot be launched

From properties --- Android and unchecked the is library check box and unchecked but this solution not useful and the exclamation mark change to red X
and this error

> Project 'appcompat_v7' is missing required source folder: 'gen'   resource appcompat_v7       location Build path

this problem only in the source file

Comment: Please provide a screen-shot of your Eclipse IDE regarding the project and what all steps you followed before you saw this issues. That may help to guide you better by SO

Comment: i do not have 10 reputation so i cant post pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the screenshots 1 & 2. Basically, you are adding appcompat_v7 libraray project to your existing project.

Right Click on the Project and follow the guidelines as showed in Screenshot -1 and Screenshot -2

That should help you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cool. Follow the same steps again and you should see appcompat_v7 listed. And it should also be visible in youre Eclipse IDE. Do vote up the Answer please...

Comment: @amoosh - Please vote up if it helped you to move ahead. By voting up, you encourage newbies like me to help further and learn by doing it for me and for others...

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the **appcompat_v7** project folder, then select *Build project*.

Eclipse will then create the **gen** subfolder and the *"Project 'appcompat_v7' is missing required source folder: 'gen'"* problem disappears, as well as the red exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the EXACT same issue as listed above, but my solution was slightly different than the one outlined by Ramakishna with the screenshots...

I actually right-clicked on the "appcompat_v7" package in the package explorer and went to Build Path > Configure Build Path. I clicked on "Android" in the left hand column and I noticed that the "Project Build Target" was set to a lower API than the project I was currently trying to create.  So, I just unchecked the Target Platform and set it to the highest possible API level/platform that I had installed.